# Php - PDO - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.'

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this function.

```
public function selection($table, $condition_var,$condition_val)
    {
        if ($condition_var != '') {

           $stm = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $condition_var=.":".$condition_var. " ");
           $stm->bindParam(":".$condition_var, $condition_val);
          return $stm->execute();
        }

    }
```

I am getting here in this below line

```
$stm = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $condition_var=.":".$condition_var. " ");
```

dont know what I am doing wrong here. kindly please check

Comment: A rogue `=` in `$condition_var=."`

Comment: I really hope all of these input parameters are carefully restricted.

Comment: is that something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to this: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

```
$stm = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $condition_var."=:condition_val");
$stm->bindParam(":condition_val", $condition_val);
```

Comment: hello sir I want to use the same variable on both end like this $condition_var =:$condition_var

Comment: so, your column name and value are the same?

Comment: no at column i am using the string variable and for the column value i am sending some value $condition_val

Comment: binding parameters actually assigns the variable. And then you need to use that assigned variable in your query.

Answer (score -1):

```
$stm = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE " . $condition_var . " = :param");
$stm->bindParam(":param", $condition_val);
```